# SpriteKit Docs in obj-C, conversion, and applying conversion to specific node in Game

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

As much as Stack is great source I spend some time reading the Objective C docs for SpriteKit. I wanted to create a run block of actions that manipulate different "Characters" SKSprite Nodes in a particular scene, "For example if you pick a particular character, and you x number of rounds, with this character, the character will disappear over time. Would this particular behavior need to be defined, in both GameScene Class, and HUD Scene? I saw this example in the Docs and this was my attempt to convert from OjC to Swift...

```
SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:100.0 duration:1.0];
SKAction *zoom = [SKAction scaleTo:2.0 duration:0.25];
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration: 0.5];
SKAction *fadeAway = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.25];
SKAction *removeNode = [SKAction removeFromParent];

SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp, zoom, wait, fadeAway, removeNode]];
[node runAction: sequence];
```

Then Swift:

```
var moveUp: SKAction = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 100.0, duration: 1.0)
var zoom: SKAction = SKAction.scaleTo(2.0, duration: 0.25)
var wait: SKAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
var fadeAway: SKAction = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.25)
var removeNode: SKAction = SKAction.removeFromParent()
var sequence: SKAction = SKAction.sequence([moveUp, zoom, wait, fadeAway, removeNode])
node.runAction(sequence)
```

This is just a test scenario, yet I am little confused on how to apply to specific node. Would this be called in touches began section where one would break out touch events for that particular node. Any feed back would be greatly appreciated.